# How to change permissions of a write protected drive to repair it?

Tags: fsck, e2fsck

My raspberry pi will no longer boot up due to the following error:

```
End Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)
```

I've tried fsck and I'm unable to get it to fix or even attempt to fix my drive:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo fsck -p /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
fsck.ext4: Read-only file system while trying to open /dev/sda2
Disk write-protected; use the -n option to do a read-only
check of the device.
```

Sadly I have some arduino sketches I would really like to recover from this drive. I can do a read only scan and see there are issues, but how do I change the protections so that fsck can try to repair it?

Here is the read scan (sudo fsck -nf /dev/sda2):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo fsck -nf /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 772 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 3589 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3700 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 3719 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 4631 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 5440 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 5441 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 6036 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 6053 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 26345 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 265227 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771825 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771825 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771825 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771825, i_size is 148618787707562243, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771825, i_blocks is 83951626, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771826 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771826 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771826 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 771826 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 771826 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771826 has imagic flag set.  Clear? no

Inode 771826 has a extra size (296) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771826, i_size is 4507998747628544, should be 60.  Fix? no

Inode 771826, i_blocks is 33686536, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771827 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771827 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771827 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771827, i_size is 16140901064495857973, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771827, i_blocks is 4104, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771828 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771828 has a extra size (1072) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771828 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771828, i_size is 576465152514195458, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771828, i_blocks is 2169503768, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771829 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771829 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771829 has a extra size (16416) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771829 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771829 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 771829, i_size is 6755399445385280, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771829, i_blocks is 74, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771830 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771830 has a bad extended attribute block 524288.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 524288 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771********* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

e2fsck: aborted

rootfs: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771830, i_size is 4503600701112341, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771830, i_blocks is 33686536, should be 15801896177070021640.  Fix? no

Inode 771831 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771831 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771831 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771831, i_size is 9840365185804536413, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771831, i_blocks is 4194312, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771832 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771832 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771832 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771832 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771832 has a bad extended attribute block 4112.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 4112 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771832 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771832, i_size is 72202731720278510, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771832, i_blocks is 2181038168, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771833 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771833 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771833 has a extra size (12320) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771833 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771833, i_blocks is 67117083, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771834 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771834 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 771834 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 771834, i_blocks is 131344, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771835 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771835 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771835 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771835, i_size is 6953557824664244236, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771835, i_blocks is 4194320, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771836 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771836 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771836 has a bad extended attribute block 4113.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 4113 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771836 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771836, i_size is 216207966485882557, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771836, i_blocks is 24, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771837 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771837 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771837 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771837 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 771837, i_size is 148618787708604416, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771837, i_blocks is 270346, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771838 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771838, i_blocks is 33686540, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771839 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771839 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771839 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771839, i_size is 13839561657061741032, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771839, i_blocks is 4112, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771840 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771840 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771840 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771840 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771840, i_size is 216172784278055494, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771840, i_blocks is 16777240, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771841 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771841 has a bad extended attribute block 2098692.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 2098692 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771841, i_size is 148618787707576904, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771841, i_blocks is 270402, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771842 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771842 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771842 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771842 has imagic flag set.  Clear? no

Inode 771842 has a extra size (4128) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771842, i_size is 4503599627439962, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771842, i_blocks is 262152, should be 15801896177070021640.  Fix? no

Inode 771843 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771843 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771843 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771843 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 771843, i_size is 10380798240600625412, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771843, i_blocks is 262152, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771845 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771845 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771845 has a bad extended attribute block 2097152.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 2097152 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771845 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771845, i_size is 6755399445389763, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771845, i_blocks is 67108872, should be 176932271371126920.  Fix? no

Inode 771846 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771846 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 771846 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 771846 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771846 has imagic flag set.  Clear? no

Inode 771846 has a extra size (296) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771846, i_size is 4503599635848405, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771846, i_blocks is 33554480, should be 15801896177070021640.  Fix? no

Inode 771847 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771847 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771847 has a bad extended attribute block 6291456.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 6291456 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771847 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771847, i_size is 1157425106382226396, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771847, i_blocks is 4194312, should be 6909130127295187080.  Fix? no

Inode 771848 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771848 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771848 has a extra size (160) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771848 has a bad extended attribute block 4097.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 4097 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771848 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771848, i_size is 216172784261274474, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771848, i_blocks is 2148532304, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771849 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771849 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771849 has a extra size (5152) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771849 has a bad extended attribute block 329216.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 329216 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771849 has illegal extended attribute value inode 523238.
Clear? no

Inode 771849 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771849, i_blocks is 32, should be 8892766049774834568.  Fix? no

Inode 771850 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771850 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 771850 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 771850, i_size is 2251800887495463, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771850, i_blocks is 35782664, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771851 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771851 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771851 has a bad extended attribute block 18874368.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 18874368 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771851 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771851 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771851 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771851 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4294967295.
Clear? no

Inode 771851 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771851, i_size is 13835058055282177670, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771851, i_blocks is 4368, should be 17124320125389786632.  Fix? no

Inode 771852 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771852 has a extra size (1200) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771852 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771852 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 771852, i_size is 14400, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771852, i_blocks is 18874368, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771853 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771853 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771853 has a extra size (20576) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771853 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771853, i_blocks is 1056778, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771854 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771854 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771854 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771854, i_blocks is 33686528, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771855 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771855, i_size is 9259541573513807567, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771855, i_blocks is 8, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771856 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771856 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771856 has a bad extended attribute block 17.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 17 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771856 has illegal extended attribute value inode 4096017.
Clear? no

Inode 771856 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771856, i_size is 216172784278048420, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771856, i_blocks is 88, should be 8892766049774834568.  Fix? no

Inode 771857 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771857 has a extra size (4192) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771857 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771857, i_size is 150870587517961694, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771857, i_blocks is 1073741834, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771858 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771858 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771858 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771858 has a extra size (416) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771858, i_size is 4503600701113609, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771858, i_blocks is 33554440, should be 15801896177070021640.  Fix? no

Inode 771859 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771859 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771859 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771859 has a extra size (16416) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771859 has an invalid extent
    (logical block 131088, invalid physical block 8592572336, len 3)
Clear? no

Inode 771859 has an invalid extent
    (logical block 0, invalid physical block 4362076160, len 0)
Clear? no

Inode 771859 has an invalid extent
    (logical block 0, invalid physical block 39977986, len 2048)
Clear? no

HTREE directory inode 771859 has an invalid root node.
Clear HTree index? no

Inode 771859 is a zero-length directory.  Clear? no

Inode 771859, i_size is 16181433463289679880, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771859, i_blocks is 4248, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771860 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771860 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771860 has a extra size (32800) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771860 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771860, i_size is 72057600480430372, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771860, i_blocks is 2702180456, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771861 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771861 has a extra size (4128) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771861 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771861, i_size is 35184376299449, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771861, i_blocks is 1048608, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771862 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771862 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771862 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771862 has a extra size (4392) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771862, i_blocks is 33686536, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771863 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771863 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771863 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771863 has a extra size (32804) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771863 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771863, i_size is 13835058058772360485, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771863, i_blocks is 24, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771864 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771864 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771864 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771864 has a extra size (176) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771864 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771864 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771864, i_size is 72057596185458043, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771864, i_blocks is 16777328, should be 8892766049774834568.  Fix? no

Inode 771865 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771865 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771865 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771865, i_blocks is 1310731, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771866 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771866 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771866, i_blocks is 33555464, should be 15801896177070021640.  Fix? no

Inode 771867 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771867 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771867 has a bad extended attribute block 524416.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 524416 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 524416 is corrupt (invalid name).  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 524416 is corrupt (allocation collision).  Clear? no

Inode 771867 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771867, i_size is 16434197992380043265, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771867, i_blocks is 4198408, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771868 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771868 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771868 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771868 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771868 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771868, i_size is 166773923717842966, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771868, i_blocks is 2685403272, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771869 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771869 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771869 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771869 has a extra size (16480) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771869 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771869, i_size is 4616189618058964450, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771869, i_blocks is 1048842, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771870 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771870 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771870 seems to have inline data but extent flag is set.
Fix? no

Inode 771870 has inline data and extent flags set but i_block contains junk.
Clear inode? no

Inode 771870 has INLINE_DATA_FL flag on filesystem without inline data support.
Clear? no

Inode 771870 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771870 has a extra size (288) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771870, i_blocks is 132104, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771871 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771871 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771871 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771871, i_size is 13839561654909534230, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771871, i_blocks is 134219784, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771872 seems to contain garbage.  Clear? no

Inode 771872 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771872 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771872 has encrypt flag but no encryption extended attribute.
Clear flag? no

Inode 771872, i_size is 72057594054714491, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771872, i_blocks is 2147483736, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771873 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771873 has a extra size (16416) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771873 has a bad extended attribute block 262144.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 262144 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771873 extent tree could be more shallow (64; could be <= 4)
Fix? no

Inode 771873 has an invalid extent
    (logical block 0, invalid physical block 203817807249413, len 1029)
Clear? no

Inode 771873 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 771873, i_size is 148618787707440519, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771873, i_blocks is 67108906, should be 8.  Fix? no

Inode 771874 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 771874 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? no

Inode 771874 has a extra size (4128) which is invalid
Fix? no

Inode 771874, i_blocks is 88, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771875 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771875, i_blocks is 24, should be 0.  Fix? no

Inode 771876 has a bad extended attribute block 4096.  Clear? no

Extended attribute block 4096 has h_blocks > 1.  Clear? no

Inode 771876 has corrupt extent header.  Clear inode? no

Inode 771876, i_blocks is 96, should be 8.  Fix? no

Error reading extended attribute block 17 (Extended attribute block has a bad header).  
rootfs: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

e2fsck: aborted

rootfs: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

Comment: How about you first save these sketches from the read-only medium? Afterwards, kid you not, SD cards are not great mediums to run a system from, so considering cost/effort vs reliability, I would consider investing in a new SD card and installing from scratch.

Comment: I'm unable to see the folders when I plug it in since it's a boot drive. Is there another way to view the folders/files?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are these files not on the damaged file system? That would be tremendously great news!

Comment: no they are only on the damaged system.  I thought you was suggesting a way to see them and copy them from this card.

Comment: Well then you should see them, right, as you're at least able to mount this thing read-only? Or are they directly affected by the data loss?

Comment: I can only see the boot folder when I plug it in.

Comment: Slight guesses: Maybe the read-only switch is switched mistakenly? And you should use another machine for recovery-trying.

Comment: The reason why you are “unable to see the folders when [you] plug it in” is that the card has two partitions, each using a different filesystem type. The boot partition uses FAT32 which is readable to Windows and Mac systems without extra drivers, but the main filesystem uses a Linux-specific `ext4` filesystem type that cannot be understood by non-Linux systems without a special filesystem driver. Do you have another **Linux** system available that could be used for recovery?

Comment: Just the raspberry pi.